# Button and Dash not lined up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add dash `-` between start time field and close time field which is not appearing correctly.

Also button is not lined up correctly too. How to solve this?

You can see example:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27015/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Open Time</label>
      <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="pg-clock"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    -
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Close Time</label>
      <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="pg-clock"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        + Add Slot
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved the dash  -  into another column. Also add some css.

```
.vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.addButton {
  margin-top: 12%;
}
```

Check result:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27017/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make another one div between two existing and put the dash into this div. And sure you need to add some css.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Open Time</label>
      <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="pg-clock"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="inner">
        -
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Close Time</label>
      <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="pg-clock"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        + Add Slot
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.form-group {
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27019/

Comment: Button is not fixed.

Comment: You can fix that via `col-` properties